# Create subset of large CSV file and write to new CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I would like to create a subset of a large CSV file using the rows that have the 4th column ass "DOT" and output to a new file.

This is the code I currently have:

```
import csv
outfile = open('DOT.csv','w')
with open('Service_Requests_2015_-_Present.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row[3] == "DOT":
            outfile.write(row)
outfile.close()
```

The error is:

```
  outfile.write(row)
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

How can I manipulate row so that I will be able to just straight up do write(row), if not, what is the easiest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine your two open statements, as the with statement accepts multiple arguments, like this:

```
import csv

infile = 'Service_Requests_2015_-_Present.csv'
outfile = 'DOT.csv'

with open(infile, encoding='utf-8') as f, open(outfile, 'w') as o:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter=',') # adjust as necessary
    for row in reader:
       if row[3] == "DOT":
           writer.writerow(row)

# no need for close statements
print('Done')
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 119: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

Make your `outfile` a `csv.writer` and use `writerow` instead of write.

```
outcsv = csv.writer(outfile, ...other_options...)
...
outcsv.writerow(row)
```

That is how I would do it... OR

```
outfile.write(",".join(row)) # comma delimited here...
```

Comment: You'd have to write the newline character as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Above code you are trying to write list with file object , we can not write list that give error "TypeError: must be str, not list"  you can convert list in string format then you able to write row in file. outfile.write(str(row))

or

```
import csv
def csv_writer(input_path,out_path):
    with open(out_path, 'ab') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        with open(input_path, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                if row[3] == "DOT":
                    writer.writerow(row)
        outfile.close()
```

csv_writer(input_path,out_path) 
[This code for Python 3 version. In Python 2.7, the open function does not take a newline argument, hence the TypeError.]